# Avoiding recursion in std::convert::TryFrom implementation for a custom enum with nested values

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement the `std::convert::TryFrom` trait for a custom `enum` called `DashNumber`. This `enum` represents numbers with infinity and negative infinity, and I want to be able to convert it to a `usize` for any type `T`. However, when I implement the conversion for `DashNumber<T>` to `usize`, it also implements it for `DashNumber<DashNumber<T>>` and so on recursively. How can I stop this recursion and only implement the conversion for the base case `DashNumber<T>`?

```rust
use core::*;
enum DashNumber<N> {
    NegInfinity,
    Number(N),
    Infinity,
}
#[derive(Debug)]
enum TryFromDashNumberError<T: std::fmt::Debug>
where
    usize: TryFrom<T>,
    <usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error: std::error::Error + 'static,
{
    NegInfinity,
    Number(<usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error),
    Infinity,
}
impl<T> fmt::Display for TryFromDashNumberError<T>
where
    usize: TryFrom<T>,
    <usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error: std::error::Error + 'static,
    T: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            TryFromDashNumberError::<T>::NegInfinity => {
                write!(f, "Negative infinity cannot be converted to a usize")
            }
            TryFromDashNumberError::<T>::Number(e) => {
                write!(f, "Error converting number to usize: {}", e)
            }
            TryFromDashNumberError::<T>::Infinity => {
                write!(f, "Infinity cannot be converted to a usize")
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<T> TryFrom<DashNumber<T>> for usize
where
    usize: TryFrom<T>,
    <usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error: std::error::Error + 'static,
    T: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    type Error = TryFromDashNumberError<T>;

    fn try_from(value: DashNumber<T>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match value {
            DashNumber::NegInfinity => Err(TryFromDashNumberError::<T>::NegInfinity),
            DashNumber::Number(n) => {
                usize::try_from(n).map_err(|e| TryFromDashNumberError::<T>::Number(e))
            }
            DashNumber::Infinity => Err(TryFromDashNumberError::<T>::Infinity),
        }
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1148df2c98962f5579b793964fcac16f)

When I try to compile my code, I get the following error:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `usize: TryFrom<_>`
  --> src/lib.rs:7:10
   |
7  | #[derive(Debug)]
   |          ^^^^^
   |
   = help: consider increasing the recursion limit by adding a `#![recursion_limit = "256"]` attribute to your crate (`playground`)
note: required for `usize` to implement `TryFrom<DashNumber<_>>`
  --> src/lib.rs:38:9
   |
38 | impl<T> TryFrom<DashNumber<T>> for usize
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^
   = note: 127 redundant requirements hidden
   = note: required for `usize` to implement `TryFrom<DashNumber<..nested DashNumber 125 times>>`
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Debug` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0275`.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the `<usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error: std::error::Error + 'static` on the enum definition. We can remove that among other bounds, and it works:

```rust
use core::fmt;
use std::error::Error;

enum DashNumber<N> {
    NegInfinity,
    Number(N),
    Infinity,
}

enum TryFromDashNumberError<T>
where
    usize: TryFrom<T>,
{
    NegInfinity,
    Number(<usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error),
    Infinity,
}
impl<T> fmt::Display for TryFromDashNumberError<T>
where
    usize: TryFrom<T>,
    <usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error: Error,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            TryFromDashNumberError::NegInfinity => {
                write!(f, "Negative infinity cannot be converted to a usize")
            }
            TryFromDashNumberError::Number(e) => {
                write!(f, "Error converting number to usize: {}", e)
            }
            TryFromDashNumberError::Infinity => {
                write!(f, "Infinity cannot be converted to a usize")
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<T> TryFrom<DashNumber<T>> for usize
where
    usize: TryFrom<T>,
    <usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error: Error,
{
    type Error = TryFromDashNumberError<T>;

    fn try_from(value: DashNumber<T>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match value {
            DashNumber::NegInfinity => Err(TryFromDashNumberError::<T>::NegInfinity),
            DashNumber::Number(n) => {
                usize::try_from(n).map_err(|e| TryFromDashNumberError::<T>::Number(e))
            }
            DashNumber::Infinity => Err(TryFromDashNumberError::<T>::Infinity),
        }
    }
}
```

You'll also need to implement `Debug` manually, since the derive macro will always add an unnecessary bound `T: Debug` and will not include the `<usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error: Debug` bound you really need:

```rust
impl<T> fmt::Debug for TryFromDashNumberError<T>
where
    usize: TryFrom<T>,
    <usize as TryFrom<T>>::Error: fmt::Debug,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            TryFromDashNumberError::NegInfinity => {
                f.debug_tuple("NegInfinity").finish()
            }
            TryFromDashNumberError::Number(e) => {
                f.debug_tuple("Infinity").field(&e).finish()
            }
            TryFromDashNumberError::Infinity => {
                f.debug_tuple("Infinity").finish()
            }
        }
    }
}
```